# Node.js Multi-page Crawler

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to crawl into website pages.
here my sample code , i used  stackoverflow just for test i dont want crawl stackoverflow.

i this code i want get every link in page and push in an array after that go to every link and search for `Node` (it's just test.)

var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

```
var pages = 20;
var counter = 1;
while(counter<=pages){

    var siteUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?page="+counter+"&tab=votes";
    var queue = [];
    request(siteUrl, function(error, response, html){
            if(!error){
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                // Extract All links in page
                links = $('a');
                $(links).each(function(i, link){
                    queue.push("http://stackoverflow.com"+$(link).attr('href'));
                    });


            }
                // Search For Node.js on every question.
                queue.each(function(i,linkItem){

                    request(linkItem, function(error, response, html){
                        var page = cheerio.load(html);
                        var ser = page.match(/node/i);
                        if (ser & ser.lenght > 0){
                            console.log(page);
                        }
                    });
                })

        })

    counter ++;
}
```

when i run this code its just show frist page link and show me error `each has no method`

i will be happy if tell where i am wrong or even my code its right solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are mixing of async and sync code is not very well.
The main problem is that the `queue` variable you are trying to iterate through has no `each` method. You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) for doing that or just replace the function call with a simple for loop.

```js
var i,
    item;

for(i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
  item = queue[i];
  
  request(item, function(error, response, html){
    var page = cheerio.load(html);
    var ser = page.match(/node/i);
    if (ser & ser.lenght > 0){
      console.log(page);
    }
  });
}
```

Besides I wrote a [tutorial](http://shrew.io/) for exactly doing what you are going try.

Comment: i used for loop , its give this error : `cannot read property 'parent' of undefined`

Comment: May you post the stacktrace please?